# How to restrict a single task

Tags: server

I want to run a single task, but in a simple jail. For instance, the executed program shouldn't be able to access any file or folder outside of its directory; And shouldn't be able to access the internet or so.

What do you suggest?

Comment: 'Simple' varies from person to person. Do you want lighweight (chroot) or easy (VM)?

Comment: @user535733, lighweight. I want to know if there's a way to restrict everything in a specific directory.  Or restrict a single executable file to access only few files and folders. (Without `chmod`. Only this specific file).

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot for clear instructions on how to easily set up a chroot. Omit chrooting /etc/resolv.conf to deny network access.